# Callback protocol with unbound method

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

```
from typing import Protocol


class MyObj:

    def my_method(self, name: str):
        pass


class Proto(Protocol):

    def __call__(self, obj: MyObj, name: str):
        pass


def my_fn(obj: MyObj, name: str):
    pass


def caller(fn: Proto):
    fn(MyObj(), 'some name')


caller(my_fn)  # passes type check
caller(MyObj.my_method)  # fails type check
```

I'm using mypy 0.971 for type checking. I have trouble understanding why the second call is illegal according to mypy. Is it in fact incorrect according to Python static typing rules?

Interestingly, if I remove the "name" parameter from all the signatures, the type check passes:

```
from typing import Protocol


class MyObj:

    def my_method(self):
        pass


class Proto(Protocol):

    def __call__(self, obj: MyObj):
        pass


def my_fn(obj: MyObj):
    pass


def caller(fn: Proto):
    fn(MyObj())


caller(my_fn)  # passes
caller(MyObj.my_method)  # passes
```

EDIT:

As per @Wombatz explanation, if I modify the protocol to be:

```
class Proto(Protocol):

    def __call__(self, obj: MyObj, /, name: str):
        pass
```

it works, since now the name of the first parameter does not matter
since it's required to be called with a positional argument.

Comment: `def my_method(self, name: str)` *does not* conform to `def __call__(self, obj: MyObj, name: str)`…?! Even if it did, calling it as static/class method will miss its `self` argument, which is probably what mypy is correctly complaining about. `MyObj().my_method` would be correct.

Comment: @deceze: `MyObj().my_method` is incorrect, and mypy is flagging it as such so I have no issues with it. `MyObj.my_method` is expected to be called as the `Proto` says, so with first argument being an instance of `MyObj` and the 2nd a string. If `caller` instread of just 'passing' called `fn(MyObj(), 'gdsgs')` the code would execute just fine. Edit: changed the code to actually call the supplied function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Protocol is more restrictive than you think.

```
class Proto(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, obj: MyObj, name: str) -> None:
        pass


def incompatible(what: MyObj, name: str) -> None:
    pass
```

The function `incompatible` is also not compatible with the protocol, because the protocol requires a callable where the first argument is a `MyObj` and **its name is `obj`** and the second argument is a `str` **and its name is `name`**.

So in theory, the protocol could be used like this:

```
def caller(p: Proto) -> None:
    p(obj=MyObj(), name="Hello")
```

This works for `my_func` but fails for the method, because the name of the first parameter of the method is `self` and not `obj`. So mypy is correct here!

You can define your protocol differently to only require a callable with two **positional** arguments of type `MyObj` and `str`

```
class Proto(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, obj: MyObj, name: str, /) -> None:
        pass
```

Now you cannot use named parameters and thus the method and my `incompatible` function are compatible with the protocol.

> Interestingly, if I remove the "name" parameter from all the signatures, the type check passes.

I cannot reproduce that. It should fail and it does